# Question about interface declaration in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am new to typescript and I am getting confused easily.

I am using react and context API to store Users.

I got this Type decleration of User:

```
export type IUser = {
  username: string;
  nickname: string;
  id: string;
  token: string;
  aboutInfo: string;
  profileImage: string;
  pendingRequests: Array<string>;
  contacts: Array<string>;
};
```

and this is my State decleration

```
export interface IState {
  user: IUser | any;
}
```

now the thing is 'User' is must be null if no user is logged in right?
so In my state I can't do something like because I am getting error:

```
export const initialState: IState = {
user: null  
  
};
```

so I thought doing something like this:

```
export interface IState {
  user: IUser | any;
}
```

The question is, is it right to do it like this?

Comment: How about `IUser | null`?

Comment: If this is the common way, I will do :) thank you!

Comment: Btw, using union type with `any` is useless. `string | any` always evaluates to `any`

Comment: Explicit `any` is such that even `any & number` is the same as just `any`. In contrast, `unknown & number` evaluates to `number`

Comment: @עמיתשוקרון I don't know how common it is, but usefulness depends on who uses it. You may even want `user: IUser | null | undefined` or `user?: IUser | null` depending on your use case.